# Getting NaN when using parseFloat

Tags: jquery, json

I am using a this code to do that calculation:

```
$('#outfitters').submit(function(event) {
                var days = $('#days').val();
                var final_price = 0;

                var length = parseFloat($("#length").val());
                var material = parseFloat($("#material").val());
                var fibre = parseFloat($("#fibre").val());
                var kevlar = parseFloat($("#kevlar").val());
                final_price = parseFloat(days * (length + material + fibre + kevlar));

                console.log(length);
                alert("Final Price is: " + final_price);
                window.location.reload(true);
        });
```

All the values are getting retrieved from a JSON which is shown below,

```
{
   "company":"SS",
   "locations":[
        { "name":"Kincardine" },
        { "name":"Killarney"},
        { "name":"Bon Echo"}
    ],
    "twelve": 25.00,
    "fourteen": 30.00,
    "sixteen":35.00,
    "paddles": 10.00,
    "lifevest": 10.00,
    "fibreglass":0.00,
    "kevlar": 10.00
}
```

The problem is I am getting NaN while calculating final_price though I an retrieve all values perfectly. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: try doing `ParseFloat` or `ParseInt` on `var days` aswell, e.g. `var days = ParseFloat($('#days').val());`

Comment: Why are you parsing a number ? Remove the parseFloat from the computation line.

Comment: `NaN` is toxic; if *one* of those values is `NaN`, *all* of them will be. Output each variable in turn to discover which one it is.

Answer (score 3):

Double check the value of your days element. Try parsing it as a float as well.

```
var days = parseFloat($('#days').val());
```

Comment: @user1890338 What is the value of `$('#days').val()` in the javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

I guess days is treated as a String:

```
var days = $('#days').val();
```

You should do a `parseFloat` on this too

Answer (score 0):

One of the values in the JSON must be NaN, so you should do validation/conversion/parse on each one before the calculation otherwise the output will be NaN.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug is to put an alert displaying value after each parseFloat statement to see which variable is causing the NaN and then sort that out.